# How to display Japanese characters in a C# GUI label

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, encoding, internationalization

I'm designing a flash card program in C#, and I have japanese characters in an SQL compact database entered using IME. The characters show up fine in the database, however when I pull them out of the database to display in a label, I get the standard 'don't know what to display' box characters.

I'm pulling the data out of the database and casting it as a string. I'm sure there is a simple fix for this but I've searched and haven't stumbled on the answer yet. Do I need to change an encoding option somewhere in my project. I'm using visual studio if that helps.

Edit: Winforms, I apologize for being vague.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, Gtk#, or some other GUI framework?

Comment: Please edit your post and/or add a tag for your gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple fix:  download a [font](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Japanese2.html) that supports Japanese characters, install it on your PC, and then set that font as the font for whatever control you're using to display the text.

Note that when deploying your software to other machines, you'll have to make sure that you also deploy this font.

Comment: And note that when deploying this font to other machines, you'll have to make sure that you have the appropriate license to redistribute it. It may not be necessary if you're targeting users with a Japanese version of Windows, because they'll already have such a font installed.

Comment: And note as well that the links I linked to are ancient and mostly dead. There's got to be one around somewhere.

Comment: That was it. Just a font that supported the character set. Knew it was going to be almost silly simple. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Arial Unicode or Kochi Mincho may be already available on a Windows installation. Free fonts: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/CJKUnifonts/Download